# Pixelmon crash minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-pixelmon

Map crashes only when pixelmon is added. Perhaps this crash is due to the size of the map. Can anyone interpret this log - thanks
How could I limit pixelmon to only spawn mons near the area I'm in, assuming that's the problem?

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Why is it breaking :(

Time: 3/27/14 4:06 PM
Description: Rendering entity in world

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 29
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.MapItemRenderer.func_78319_a(SourceFile:44)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_82402_b(SourceFile:150)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_82404_a(SourceFile:44)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_76986_a(SourceFile:20)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager.func_78719_a(RenderManager.java:312)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager.func_78720_a(RenderManager.java:281)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderGlobal.func_72713_a(RenderGlobal.java:524)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1160)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78480_b(EntityRenderer.java:1006)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:946)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:838)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.MapItemRenderer.func_78319_a(SourceFile:44)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_82402_b(SourceFile:150)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_82404_a(SourceFile:44)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_76986_a(SourceFile:20)

-- Entity being rendered --
Details:
    Entity Type: ItemFrame (net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItemFrame)
    Entity ID: 57
    Entity Name: entity.ItemFrame.name
    Entity's Exact location: -239.50, 51.50, 83.06
    Entity's Block location: World: (-240,51,83), Chunk: (at 0,3,3 in -15,5; contains blocks -240,0,80 to -225,255,95), Region: (-1,0; contains chunks -32,0 to -1,31, blocks -512,0,0 to -1,255,511)
    Entity's Momentum: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

-- Renderer details --
Details:
    Assigned renderer: net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame@7538a289
    Location: 6.89,-14.12,-8.85 - World: (6,-15,-9), Chunk: (at 6,-1,7 in 0,-1; contains blocks 0,0,-16 to 15,255,-1), Region: (0,-1; contains chunks 0,-32 to 31,-1, blocks 0,0,-512 to 511,255,-1)
    Rotation: -180.0
    Delta: 0.038746357
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager.func_78719_a(RenderManager.java:312)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager.func_78720_a(RenderManager.java:281)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderGlobal.func_72713_a(RenderGlobal.java:524)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1160)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['ratzy'/327, l='MpServer', x=-246.39, y=65.62, z=91.91]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 441
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (-249,64,91), Chunk: (at 7,4,11 in -16,5; contains blocks -256,0,80 to -241,255,95), Region: (-1,0; contains chunks -32,0 to -1,31, blocks -512,0,0 to -1,255,511)
    Level time: 152284625 game time, 8932907 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 108 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['ratzy'/327, l='MpServer', x=-246.39, y=65.62, z=91.91],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/10, l='MpServer', x=-383.50, y=45.50, z=104.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/11, l='MpServer', x=-366.50, y=55.50, z=107.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/12, l='MpServer', x=-367.50, y=55.50, z=108.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/13, l='MpServer', x=-347.50, y=71.50, z=-4.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/14, l='MpServer', x=-348.50, y=71.50, z=-3.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/19, l='MpServer', x=-304.50, y=56.50, z=67.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/18, l='MpServer', x=-305.50, y=56.50, z=68.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/21, l='MpServer', x=-315.50, y=57.50, z=82.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/20, l='MpServer', x=-314.50, y=57.50, z=81.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/28, l='MpServer', x=-258.50, y=53.50, z=15.06],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/31, l='MpServer', x=-259.50, y=31.50, z=190.06],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/32, l='MpServer', x=-262.50, y=38.50, z=199.06],
        EntityPig['Pig'/42, l='MpServer', x=-252.50, y=69.00, z=31.25],
        EntityItem['item.item.rottenFlesh'/43, l='MpServer', x=-250.78, y=64.13, z=42.06],
        EntityVillager['Villager'/40, l='MpServer', x=-252.31, y=57.00, z=19.00],
        EntityVillager['Villager'/41, l='MpServer', x=-252.69, y=57.00, z=19.00],
        EntityPixelmon['Diglett'/319, l='MpServer', x=-229.50, y=41.00, z=141.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/44, l='MpServer', x=-243.50, y=51.50, z=84.06],
        EntitySquid['Squid'/45, l='MpServer', x=-240.78, y=56.19, z=124.25],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/55, l='MpServer', x=-236.50, y=58.50, z=27.06],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/384, l='MpServer', x=-115.50, y=49.50, z=43.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/58, l='MpServer', x=-234.50, y=18.50, z=199.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/57, l='MpServer', x=-239.50, y=51.50, z=83.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/56, l='MpServer', x=-228.50, y=51.50, z=88.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/342, l='MpServer', x=-236.50, y=55.50, z=-52.94],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/31, l='MpServer', x=-259.50, y=31.50, z=190.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/67, l='MpServer', x=-186.50, y=54.50, z=-29.94],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/76, l='MpServer', x=-168.50, y=46.00, z=14.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/77, l='MpServer', x=-160.06, y=46.50, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/78, l='MpServer', x=-175.94, y=46.50, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/79, l='MpServer', x=-175.94, y=46.50, z=23.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/85, l='MpServer', x=-160.06, y=46.50, z=22.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/326, l='MpServer', x=-109.50, y=50.50, z=-38.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/84, l='MpServer', x=-160.06, y=46.50, z=23.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/87, l='MpServer', x=-160.06, y=46.50, z=20.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/86, l='MpServer', x=-160.06, y=46.50, z=21.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/325, l='MpServer', x=-120.50, y=50.50, z=139.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/81, l='MpServer', x=-175.94, y=46.50, z=21.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/80, l='MpServer', x=-175.94, y=46.50, z=22.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/83, l='MpServer', x=-175.94, y=46.50, z=19.50],
        EntityPixelmon['Aron'/320, l='MpServer', x=-332.50, y=20.00, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/82, l='MpServer', x=-175.94, y=46.50, z=20.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/93, l='MpServer', x=-163.94, y=46.50, z=23.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/92, l='MpServer', x=-163.94, y=46.50, z=22.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/95, l='MpServer', x=-166.06, y=46.50, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/94, l='MpServer', x=-163.94, y=46.50, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/89, l='MpServer', x=-163.94, y=46.50, z=19.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/331, l='MpServer', x=-387.50, y=45.50, z=104.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/88, l='MpServer', x=-160.06, y=46.50, z=19.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/91, l='MpServer', x=-163.94, y=46.50, z=21.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/90, l='MpServer', x=-163.94, y=46.50, z=20.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/102, l='MpServer', x=-169.94, y=46.50, z=20.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/373, l='MpServer', x=-127.50, y=48.50, z=-39.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/103, l='MpServer', x=-169.94, y=46.50, z=21.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/100, l='MpServer', x=-166.06, y=46.50, z=19.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/375, l='MpServer', x=-127.50, y=53.50, z=-41.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/101, l='MpServer', x=-169.94, y=46.50, z=19.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/374, l='MpServer', x=-127.50, y=53.50, z=-38.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/369, l='MpServer', x=-132.50, y=41.50, z=-52.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/98, l='MpServer', x=-166.06, y=46.50, z=21.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/99, l='MpServer', x=-166.06, y=46.50, z=20.50],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/371, l='MpServer', x=-125.50, y=30.50, z=-51.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/96, l='MpServer', x=-166.06, y=46.50, z=23.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/97, l='MpServer', x=-166.06, y=46.50, z=22.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/110, l='MpServer', x=-172.06, y=46.50, z=21.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/381, l='MpServer', x=-113.50, y=54.50, z=0.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/111, l='MpServer', x=-172.06, y=46.50, z=20.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/380, l='MpServer', x=-116.50, y=54.50, z=-1.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/108, l='MpServer', x=-172.06, y=46.50, z=23.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/383, l='MpServer', x=-122.50, y=49.50, z=43.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/109, l='MpServer', x=-172.06, y=46.50, z=22.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/106, l='MpServer', x=-169.94, y=46.50, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/377, l='MpServer', x=-112.94, y=54.50, z=-2.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/107, l='MpServer', x=-172.06, y=46.50, z=24.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/376, l='MpServer', x=-124.50, y=53.50, z=-41.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/104, l='MpServer', x=-169.94, y=46.50, z=22.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/379, l='MpServer', x=-113.50, y=54.50, z=-1.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/105, l='MpServer', x=-169.94, y=46.50, z=23.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/378, l='MpServer', x=-114.06, y=54.50, z=-2.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/356, l='MpServer', x=-151.50, y=40.50, z=-51.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/358, l='MpServer', x=-135.50, y=29.50, z=-52.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/355, l='MpServer', x=-148.50, y=40.50, z=-51.94],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/112, l='MpServer', x=-172.06, y=46.50, z=19.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/127, l='MpServer', x=-158.50, y=41.50, z=11.06],
        EntityPixelmon['Pachirisu'/410, l='MpServer', x=-328.50, y=76.00, z=53.50],
        EntityPixelmon['Seaking'/414, l='MpServer', x=-264.47, y=57.77, z=188.69],
        EntityPixelmon['Seaking'/415, l='MpServer', x=-260.47, y=57.43, z=185.31],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/129, l='MpServer', x=-158.06, y=31.50, z=29.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/128, l='MpServer', x=-155.50, y=41.50, z=11.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/131, l='MpServer', x=-158.50, y=36.50, z=17.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/130, l='MpServer', x=-156.06, y=41.50, z=31.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/132, l='MpServer', x=-156.06, y=41.50, z=33.50],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/393, l='MpServer', x=-110.50, y=49.50, z=43.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/392, l='MpServer', x=-104.50, y=49.50, z=43.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/396, l='MpServer', x=-105.50, y=49.50, z=154.06],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/386, l='MpServer', x=-114.06, y=48.50, z=43.50],
        EntityItemFrame['entity.ItemFrame.name'/385, l='MpServer', x=-112.94, y=48.50, z=43.50],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/384, l='MpServer', x=-115.50, y=49.50, z=43.06],
        EntityPixelmon['Eevee'/424, l='MpServer', x=-224.30, y=64.00, z=-8.00],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/393, l='MpServer', x=-110.50, y=49.50, z=43.06],
        EntityPixelmon['Magikarp'/418, l='MpServer', x=-271.69, y=57.68, z=174.28],
        EntityPixelmon['Diglett'/421, l='MpServer', x=-242.50, y=32.00, z=91.50],
        EntityPixelmon['Solrock'/420, l='MpServer', x=-244.50, y=32.00, z=91.50],
        EntityPixelmon['Minun'/423, l='MpServer', x=-271.75, y=64.00, z=-4.59],
        EntityPixelmon['Minun'/422, l='MpServer', x=-325.78, y=66.27, z=27.47],
        EntityPixelmon['Magikarp'/214, l='MpServer', x=-240.75, y=59.34, z=114.53],
        EntityPainting['Painting'/371, l='MpServer', x=-125.50, y=30.50, z=-51.06]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
    Server brand: fml,forge
    Server type: Non-integrated multiplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient.func_72914_a(WorldClient.java:440)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71396_d(Minecraft.java:2312)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:856)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.6.4
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_05, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 183301848 bytes (174 MB) / 472580096 bytes (450 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G
    AABB Pool Size: 17815 (997640 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 1416 (79296 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 3, tallocated: 63
    FML: MCP v8.11 FML v6.4.45.953 Minecraft Forge 9.11.1.953 6 mods loaded, 6 mods active
    mcp{8.09} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    FML{6.4.45.953} [Forge Mod Loader] (minecraftforge-9.11.1.953.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Forge{9.11.1.953} [Minecraft Forge] (minecraftforge-9.11.1.953.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    battlegear2{1.0.5.3} [Mine & Blade Battlegear 2 - Bullseye] ([1.6.4] Mine & Blade Battlegear 2 - Bullseye - 1.0.5.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    meteors{2.11.2} [Falling Meteors] (Meteors Mod V2.11.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    pixelmon{3.0.2} [Pixelmon] (Pixelmon 3.0.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Launched Version: 1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.953
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.4.0, NVIDIA Corporation
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Pack: PokeBox (R6).zip
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 2489 (139384 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 788 (44128 bytes; 0 MB) used
```

Comment: My guess is that Battle Gear alters the player's UI some how.. Mods that alter the UI are not usually compatible with pixelmon.

Comment: @James Except the stack trace is saying that it's failing on rendering a map in an item frame.  Unless that's how minimaps are rendered, it's probably not a mod that's causing the problem.

Comment: @MBraedley True enough. ID Conflict when adding in Pixelmon then.

Comment: @James Wouldn't be an ID conflict as it'd spit out another error. I agree with the map conflict hunch though, as the trace clearly has `net.minecraft.client.gui.MapItemRenderer.func_78319_a` in it, leading me to believe it's conflicting mods.

Comment: Ok, Last stab at this. This is not the world rendering this is a Map object. My guess is that it is in an item frame since the 'Entity Being Rendered' section is saying its an item frame. It is trying to update something but was given an Id that it does not like. If you look in the entity lists, which I have reformatted, you will see that there is no Id 29. I do not know why it is looking for it or what it is supposed to be but that is the crash. Is this the map Id, is it an item in the world? No idea. It just does not like that Id for some reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for modded minecraft.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, lets break this down piece by piece. If you aren't interested skip to the end

`Description: Rendering entity in world`

This means that an entity in the world is causing a crash while being rendered. A common cause of this is that an entity from a mod in your world has an issue with the model.

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 29`

This means that an array in the render code contains less than 30 objects but the 30th object is trying to be accessed.

> at net.minecraft.client.gui.MapItemRenderer.func_78319_a(SourceFile:44)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_82402_b(SourceFile:150)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_82404_a(SourceFile:44)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.RenderItemFrame.func_76986_a(SourceFile:20)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager.func_78719_a(RenderManager.java:312)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderManager.func_78720_a(RenderManager.java:281)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderGlobal.func_72713_a(RenderGlobal.java:524)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(EntityRenderer.java:1160)
>       at net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer.func_78480_b(EntityRenderer.java:1006)
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:946)
>       at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:838)
>       at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
>       at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)

This means that a map in a item frame is failing to render.

> -- Entity being rendered --
>   Details:
>       Entity Type: ItemFrame (net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItemFrame)
>       Entity ID: 57
>       Entity Name: entity.ItemFrame.name
>       **Entity's Exact location: -239.50, 51.50, 83.06**
>       Entity's Block location: World: (-240,51,83), Chunk: (at 0,3,3 in -15,5; contains blocks -240,0,80 to -225,255,95), Region: (-1,0; contains chunks -32,0 to -1,31, blocks -512,0,0 to -1,255,511)
>       Entity's Momentum: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

This is the entity that is failing to render. Take note of the coodinates (highlighted), you'll need them in a second. That's really all that matters to solve this.

---

### Now, on to fixing it

First of all, If you don't have it already, download [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). Open it and click *"Open a level..."*

[image: Home screen of MCEdit with 'Open a Level' highlighted]

Navigate to your saves folder and open the world.

[image: Browsing for a level]

Hit ESC to open the menu, click "Goto", and type the coordinates of the entity (you wrote them down earlier) in the box.

x: -239, y: 51, z: 83

[image: The Esc Menu showing the Goto Box]

You should see a brown box. While looking at it, right-click and then double-click. Click "Delete Entities"

[image: Double-click menu showing 'Delete Entities' highlighted]

Finally, hit ESC, click "Save", and click "Quit"

[image: Esc Menu showing 'Save' and 'Quit']

Load the world up in Minecraft and it shouldn't crash.